# Google protobuff enum: In .NET How to extract value from OriginalNameAttribute

Tags: .net, enums, protocol-buffers

In a proto file I have defined:

```
syntax = "proto3";

enum MyEnum {
    THIS_IS_VAL_1 = 0,
    THIS_IS_VAL_2 = 1
}
```

Then in my c# client I see the generated enum like:

```
public enum MyEnum {
    [pbr::OriginalName("THIS_IS_VAL_1")] ThisIsVal1 = 0,
    [pbr::OriginalName("THIS_IS_VAL_2")] ThisIsVal2 = 1
}
```

Is there a simple way to get the original name as defined in this generated attribute?

Comment: You can get it using reflection but why do you want this in the first place? The code will use the enum members and values, not the original name. If you want to display the values a certain way you should use the `DisplayName` attribute. If you want the enum members to have the same name, change their names to `THIS_IS_VAL_1` and `THS_IS_VAL_2` and ignore the styling warnings, but why do that?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos If you tell me that I can force the naming of the generated enum values, then I'm happy.
The goal is to use the enum value's name as an identifier when doing queries by key.